# How to store list of objects that have different properties in django db?

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, django-models

It is straightforward to store in mysql data like

```
[
    {
        'name': 'Object1', 
        'color': 'red', 
        'shape': 'ellipse'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Object2',
        'color': 'green',
        'shape': 'circle'
    }
]
```

But what if object has different number of attributes (attributes are flat, they are not nested)?

```
[
    {
        'name': 'Object1', 
        'color': 'red', 
        'shape': 'ellipse',
        'eccentricity': 0.5
    },
    {
        'name': 'Object2',
        'color': 'green',
        'shape': 'circle'
        'radius': 5
    }
]
```

There are many attributes, so sub-classing is not solution.

How do I handle it in mysql? Or if this is not possible, maybe postgresql?

What about non-relational databases, what is the best to use?

I need to make queries based on those attributes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is [`JsonField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) in postgres which can be used for this kind of tasks. Also there is many apps for django which add `JsonField` that can work with mysql like [`django-extensions`](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) for example

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're avoiding subclassing, it's built pretty much for this purpose. The best way to do this is subclassing. For this example, it looks like you'd probably want to use the `shape` attribute as the major class. For example, you could create a Shape class thusly:

```
class Shape(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Circle(Shape):
    radius = FloatField()

class Ellipse(Shape):
    eccentricity = FloatField()
```

This would create two tables in your model, a `Circle` table with a `color` and `radius` column, as well as a `Ellipse` table with a `color` and a `eccentricity` column.

If you really want to avoid subclassing for some reason, and you are using PostgreSQL, you can declare a `JSONField` (probably called attributes or something similar) of the different values. They would be harder to access programmatically, though. That would look like this:

```
class Shape(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    attributes = models.JSONField()
```